# Promise not returning anything?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I've been trying to convert my promise syntax from then/catch to async/await and for some reason it's now unable to return my promise.
This is the then/catch version which returns the data perfectly fine

```
let lotFiles = []

export function returnData(key) {
  getContentWithKey(key)
  .then(content => {
    if (content.previousHash === '') {
      lotFiles.push(content)
      return lotFiles
    }
    lotFiles.push(content)
    returnData(content.previousHash)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

This is the async/await version which doesn't return anything at all

```
let lotFiles = []

async function returnData(key) {
  try {
    let content = await getContentWithKey(key)
    if (content.previousHash === '') {
      lotFiles.push(content)
      return lotFiles
    } else {
      lotFiles.push(content)
      returnData(content.previousHash)
    }
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
}
```

---

I have another function that calls returnData -

```
async function returnContent(data) {
  let something = await getContent(data)
  console.log(something)
}

returnContent()
```

Comment: Your top code shouldn't be returning anything either... it's not returning the Promise chain

Comment: Meanwhile your bottom code *should* be returning a Promise, and thus should be invoked either with `await` or with `.then(...)` on it.

Comment: So how do I get the code to return `lotFiles`?  It's able to log it, but unable to return it

Comment: @JorahFriendzone how are you verifying that it is _not_ working?

Comment: Code goes in your question, **not in the comments**

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async/await` requires a promise chain.

The `returnData()` function is recursive so you can place the inner most result in an array and push the other results in the chain.

```
async function returnData(key) {
  try {
    const content = await getContentWithKey(key)
    if (content.previousHash === '') {
      // termination of recursion
      // resolve with an array containing the content
      return Promise.resolve([content])
    }
    else {
      return returnData(content.previousHash).then(function(result) {
        // append the result and pass the array back up the chain
        return [content].concat(result)
      })
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
}
```

You can replace the inner promise chain with `await`.

```
async function returnData(key) {
  try {
    const content = await getContentWithKey(key)
    if (content.previousHash === '') {
      // termination of recursion
      // resolve with an array containing the content
      return Promise.resolve([content])
    }
    else {
      try {
        let result = await returnData(content.previousHash)
        // append the result and pass the new array back up the chain
        return [content].concat(result)
      }
      catch(error) {
        return Promise.reject(error)
      }
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
}
```